# Is there a way to get Tier Price List in our custom module template file

Tags: magento2, tierprice

As we use in :

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_composer/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/tier_prices.phtml
```

How can i use `getTierPriceList()` in my custom module's template file ?

also is it available in product collection ?

I tried a lot but is unable to load product collection as we used to do in magento 1.x.

Tried:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2);
```

in this

```
$product->getPrice();
```

is working but how can i get tierprice in template file? 
i.e. my main concern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the tier price by below code.

```
$tierPrices = [];

$tierPricesList = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('tier_price')->getTierPriceList();

foreach ($tierPricesList as $tierPrice) {
    $tierPrices[] = $this->priceCurrency->convert($tierPrice['price']->getValue());
}
```

For more details observe the core module code.

\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\View.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: Getting Blank page every time ..

Comment: Check the error log, it will work and refer the code in the mentioned file.

Comment: Hi @krishnaijjadaati95Dev how to get this info in  `Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml`?